# NameError: name 'Alabama' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

So basically I have to do a coding project about all 50 states and need individual GUIS for the state flag, flower, bird, and capital. So far I have Alabama, Arkansas and Alaska. I can choose Alabama just fine but whenever I try to choose Alaska it error codes me saying "Alabama is not defined". So I put all the code for Alabama into a comment and try to do Arkansas. That works just fine, but then I try Alaska and it gives me the same error I was getting before, but this time being "Arkansas is not defined" So whatever state is above the others works just fine but any state under it gives me the "(X) is not defined" for the top state.

Here is my code. Can anyone try to help me figure out why it is giving me this error?

```
import Tkinter as tk




   

state=raw_input("What State are you learning about today? ")


 #Alabama Start------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

chances=0
while chances<10:
   if state=="Alabama":
      Alabama=raw_input("What do you want to learn about? (Type: Flag, Flower, Capital, Bird) ")

   if Alabama=="Flag":
      print("Flag Date Adopted: 1895 ")
      print("Flag Representation: ")
      alabamaFlagGui=tk.Tk()
      alabamaFlagGui.title("Alabama Flag")
      alabamaFlagGui.geometry("300x300")
      flag=tk.PhotoImage(file="Alabama.gif")
      flags=tk.Label(image=flag)
      flags.pack()




   if Alabama=="Flower":
      print("Flower Genus: ")
      print("Flower Scientific Name: ")
      print("Flower Medical Uses: ")
      alabamaFlowerGui=tk.Tk()
      alabamaFlowerGui.title("Alabama Flower")
      alabamaFlowerGui.geometry("300x300")
      flower=tk.PhotoImage(file="alabamaFlower.gif")
      flowers=tk.Label(image=flower)
      flowers.pack()
      flowers.mainloop()  
 
   if Alabama=="Bird":
      alabamaBirdGui=tk.Tk()
      alabamaBirdGui.title("Alabama Bird")
      alabamaBirdGui.geometry("300x300")
      bird=tk.PhotoImage(file="alabamaBird.gif")
      birds=tk.Label(image=bird)
      birds.pack()
      birds.mainloop()
            
#Alabama End--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


#Arkansas Start-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

chances=0
while chances<10:
   if state=="Arkansas":
      Arkansas=raw_input("What do you want to learn about? (Type: Flag, Flower, Capital, Bird) ")
   
   if Arkansas=="Flag":
      print("Flag Date Adopted: 1895 ")
      print("Flag Representation: ")
      arkansasFlagGui=tk.Tk()
      arkansasFlagGui.title("Arkansas Flag")
      arkansasFlagGui.geometry("300x300")
      flag=tk.PhotoImage(file="Arkansas.gif")
      flags=tk.Label(image=flag)
      flags.pack()




   if Arkansas=="Flower":
      print("Flower Genus: ")
      print("Flower Scientific Name: ")
      print("Flower Medical Uses: ")
      arkansasFlowerGui=tk.Tk()
      arkansasFlowerGui.title("Arkansas Flower")
      arkansasFlowerGui.geometry("300x300")
      flower=tk.PhotoImage(file="arkansasFlower.gif")
      flowers=tk.Label(image=flower)
      flowers.pack()
      flowers.mainloop()  
 
   if Arkansas=="Bird":
      arkansasBirdGui=tk.Tk()
      arkansasBirdGui.title("Alabama Bird")
      arkansasBirdGui.geometry("300x300")
      bird=tk.PhotoImage(file="arkansasBird.gif")
      birds=tk.Label(image=bird)
      birds.pack()
      birds.mainloop()
 
 
   if Arkansas=="Capital":
      arkansasCapitalGui=tk.Tk()
      arkansasCapitalGui.title("Alabama Bird")
      arkansasCapitalGui.geometry("300x300")
      capital=tk.PhotoImage(file="arkansasBird.gif")
      capitals=tk.Label(image=bird)
      capitals.pack()
      capitals.mainloop()
           
#Arkansas End--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


#Alaska Start--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

chances=0
while chances<10:
   if state=="Alaska":
      Alaska=raw_input("What do you want to learn about? (Type: Flag, Flower, Capital, Bird) ")
   
   if Alaska=="Flag":
      print("Flag Date Adopted: 1895 ")
      print("Flag Representation: ")
      alaskaFlagGui=tk.Tk()
      alaskaFlagGui.title("Alaska Flag")
      arkansasFlagGui.geometry("300x300")
      flag=tk.PhotoImage(file="Alaska.gif")
      flags=tk.Label(image=flag)
      flags.pack()




   if Alaska=="Flower":
      print("Flower Genus: ")
      print("Flower Scientific Name: ")
      print("Flower Medical Uses: ")
      alaskaFlowerGui=tk.Tk()
      alaskaFlowerGui.title("Arkansas Flower")
      alaskaFlowerGui.geometry("300x300")
      flower=tk.PhotoImage(file="alaskaFlower.gif")
      flowers=tk.Label(image=flower)
      flowers.pack()
      flowers.mainloop()  
 
   if alaska=="Bird":
      alaskaBirdGui=tk.Tk()
      alaskaBirdGui.title("Alaska Bird")
      alaskaBirdGui.geometry("300x300")
      bird=tk.PhotoImage(file="alaskaBird.gif")
      birds=tk.Label(image=bird)
      birds.pack()
      birds.mainloop()
 
 
   if alaska=="Capital":
      alaskaCapitalGui=tk.Tk()
      alaskaCapitalGui.title("Alaska Bird")
      alaskaCapitalGui.geometry("300x300")
      capital=tk.PhotoImage(file="AlaskaBird.gif")
      capitals=tk.Label(image=bird)
      capitals.pack()
      capitals.mainloop()
           
#Alaska End---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What happens if the expression in your first `if` does not become `True`?

Comment: `raw_input` suggests you're using Python 2. It has been deprecated for over 2 years now. You should absolutely upgrade to Python 3.

Comment: Is it just me, or are all of these while loops infinite?

Answer (score 1):

You have to **instantiate** the variable before using it for conditional logic.

In you code, things work out in the beginning as you set the state and the first state's variable gets instantiated/created (lets say `Alaska`) inside the `if` statement. But after that loop is done, for the next states - as the `state` variable is still set to the first state it never enters the `state == 'Arkansas'`.

To fix it, either instantiate the variable before as empty strings `Arkansas= ''` or set the `state` variable to the next state before entering the while loop so that the `if` is triggered.

**PS** you have other bugs like misspelling the states - `Alaska` and `alaska` - remember that these are variable names so case matters